# MongoDB group two separate fields as one array or something with same fieldname

Tags: mongodb, distinct, aggregation-framework

I'm sorry if the title is not descriptive, I didn't know how to express my problem better.

I have a CD database that contains this kind of data:

```
{
"albumInfo": {
    "name": "Angels Fall First",
    "type": "LP",
    "genre": ["symphonic metal", "power metal", "folk metal"],
    "publicationYear": 1997,
    "tags":["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    "stars": 4
},

"artist": {
    "name":"Nightwish",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "Tarja Turunen",
            "instruments": ["lead vocals"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Tuomas Holopainen",
            "instruments": ["piano", "synthesizers", "keyboards", "vocals"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Erno Vuorinen",
            "instruments": ["guitar"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Jukka Nevalainen",
            "instruments": ["drums", "percussion"]
        }
    ]
},

"additionalArtists": [
    {
        "name": "Esa Lehtinen",
        "instruments": ["flutes"]
    }
]
```

And I want to have additionalArtists.name and artist.members.name in one array or at least so that they have same field name (like "musician.name") so that I can fetch distinct musicians from the database.

My database isn't very well formatted I guess but this kind of weird db should do it for now.

Is aggregate $project my solution?

Comment: What is your query filter ? Do you want distinct name in each document or across multlple document ?

Comment: I'm new with non-sql vocabulary so I'm not quite sure but I have db that has many CD:s like the one that I posted above. And I want to do query that gives me all the musicians that are in the database. And musicians are stored in two places like in the data example ("additionalArtists.name" and "artist.members.name") 

did I answer the question?

I guess it's across multiple documents.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Let me add an answer and we can work from there. What is your mongo version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$setUnion` to merge both musicians array and get the all distinct `musicians` in a single document followed by `$unwind` so you can `$group` `musicians` with `$addToSet` to get distinct across all documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
     { $project: { musician: { $setUnion: [ ["$artist.name"], "$additionalArtists.name" ] }, _id: 0 } },
     { $unwind: "$musician"},
     { $group: {_id:null , musician: {$addToSet:"$musician" } }}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's almost what I needed. Only modifications I had to make was that I changed "$artist.name" to "$artist.members.name" inside $setUnion. 

The result doesn't come in one array, so if I needed to use this data in program it would still need some modification, but for now this works for me.

Comment: You are welcome. Get rid of [] because `artist.members.name` is an array. The only reason I use [] because  `artist.name` is a field  and set union only takes array.

Comment: Aight, I actually changed few things in the db to make everything work a bit simplier, but your point still stands. Thanks.